# Excel Substrings

Tags: excel, substring

I have two unordered sets of data here:

```
blah blah:2020:50::7.1:45
movie blah:blahbah, The:1914:54:
```

I want to extract all the data to the left of the year (aka, 1915 and 1914). 
What excel formula would I use for this?

I tried this formula
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":",A1)),MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1),300),A1)
these were the results below:

```
: blahblah, The:1914:54::7
:1915:50::7.1:45:
```

This is because there is a colon in the movie title.

The results I need consistently are:

```
:1914:54::7.9:17::
:1915:50::7.1:45::
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expressions, make sure you include a reference for it in your VBA editor. The following UDF will do the job.

```
Function ExtractNumber(cell As Range) As String
    ExtractNumber = ""
    Dim rex As New RegExp
    rex.Pattern = "(:\d{4}:\d{2}::\d\.\d:\d{2}::\d:\d:\d:\d:\d:\d:\d)"
    rex.Global = True
    Dim mtch As Object, sbmtch As Object
    For Each mtch In rex.Execute(cell.Value)
        ExtractNumber = ExtractNumber & mtch.SubMatches(0)
    Next mtch
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Without VBA:**

In reality you don't want to find the **:**  You want to find either **:1** or **:2** since the year will either start with **1** or **2**
This formula should do it:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(":1",A1,1),9999),IFERROR(FIND(":2",A1),9999)),9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a four digit string, in a certain range, bounded by colons.

For example:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND(":" &ROW(INDIRECT("1900:2100"))&":",A1 &":" &ROW(INDIRECT("1900:2100"))&":")),99)
```

entered as an array formula by holding down `ctrl-shift` while hitting `Enter` would ensure years in the range 1900 to 2100.  Change those values as appropriate for your data.  The 99 at the end represents the longest possible string.  Again, that can be increased as required.

You can use the same approach to return just the left hand part, up to the colon preceding the year:

```
=LEFT(A1,-1+MIN(FIND(":" &ROW(INDIRECT("1900:2100"))&":",A1 &":" &ROW(INDIRECT("1900:2100"))&":")))
```

Here is a screen shot, showing the original data in B1:B2, with the results of the first part in B4:B5, and the formula for B4 showing in the formula bar.

The results for the 2nd part are in B7:B9

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! The mid function worked like a charm from Gary's comment.

Comment: How would I now also keep everything before the year?:  aka in my example blahblah, The:

Comment: `=A1`  would **also** keep everything before the year.  If you just want to return the information prior to the year, use the same `FIND` parameter (minus 1) but use the `LEFT` function.

Comment: Substitute the result of your first formula with nothing.

=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND(":1",A1,1),9999),IFERROR(FIND(":2",A1),9999)),9999),"")

Comment: @Dan I used your formula but stil lgot cases where the : was not added to the title for results prior to the year

Comment: Thanks Ron, but I'm getting the full result with your formula of the entire string rather than just one part.

Comment: @Sanch That is because you entered it normally, rather than as an array formula with `ctrl-shift-enter`  (The same as the original, where I mentioned how to properly enter the formula).

Comment: @ Ron - I'm pretty sure the squiggles are arrays

Comment: @Sanch Did you type in the squiggles?

Comment: @Sanch It is working properly here, after copying and pasting in your examples.  I'll post a screenshot

Comment: thanks ron i'll restart maybe its a memory issue on my laptop

Comment: copying and pasting the formula using array still doesn't work . I must be silly!

Comment: @Sanch The only way I can get it to return the entire string, using the strings you have pasted above, is by entering the formula normally, with just `enter`.  See if downloading this file helps [Title Extract Text](http://1drv.ms/17xV5h7)

Comment: @sanch. I cannot be sure since I cannot see formula on my phone, but did you properly adjust the year parameter to include the 1800's?

Comment: @sanch I see now you did I adjust year parameters. When I get to a computer that can run the Excel, I will  check the file.

Comment: @Sanch I downloaded the file you posted and the formula in B1 is **NOT** array entered.  There are no braces around the formula.  If I edit B1, and then `ctrl-shift-enter`, the formula returns just the title.